# UITextField background image not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I need to add background image in UITextField with left view mode also showing image. I have added both of them and its working. However my text content is stick to UITextField bottom. I need to give space between textfield and content.

[image]

Below is my code with image.

```
UITextField *textField = [UITextField new];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
textField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"form-control.png"];
textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
textField.placeholder = @"Email/Phone no";
textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:16];

UIImageView *phoneImageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 21)];
phoneImageView.frame = CGRectInset(phoneImageView.frame, -5, 0);
[phoneImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"phone.png"]];
[phoneImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
textField.leftView = phoneImageView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

Comment: Your CGRectInset to set the frame of the phoneImageView simply re-uses the frame you defined on the previously line.  Was this really intended? Would be simpler to update your CGRectMake

Comment: i have used auto layout for setting the frame of uitextfield. CGRectInset was just to give space between left image and text.

Answer (score 2):

you must set your textfield border-style square for keep image in your text-field as a background like this :

For Square:-

```
    [textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
```

For set background image

```
  [textField setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.jpg"]];
```

Comment: This worked for me, images were not showing after upgrading to iOS 14 on Xcode 12, but setting the border style to square did the trick.

Comment: This worked for me when border image wasn't showing after upgrading to iOS 14!

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I've solved this by using a UIImageView for the background of the textfield, and using auto-layout to attach the UIImageView frame to match the frame of the UITextField.  Once that's done, you can customize the margins between the textfield and the UIImageView by updating the constraints.